# defining a topology on a group by defining a fundamental system of neighborhoods of zero

Tags: abstract-algebra, general-topology

Let $G$ be an abelian group and $\left\{G_i\right\}$ a family of subgroups. I would like to make sure i fully understand what we mean when we say that "we take the $\left\{G_i\right\}$ to be a fundamental system of neighborhoods of zero, thus making $G$ into a topological group".

Interpretation 1: this means that we define for every point $x \in G$ a fundamental system of neighborhoods to be $\left\{x + G_i \right\}$. This defines a topology on $G$. From this it follows that the addition map is continuous, since the inverse image of the open set $y+G_i$ under addition with $x$ is the open set $y-x+G_i$.

Interpretation 2: this means that we define only the neighborhoods of $0$ to be $\left\{G_i\right\}$ plus the addition map to be continuous. We further define the open sets to be inverse images of the sets $G_i$ under addition maps. Then the inverse image of the open set $G_i$ under addition with $-x$ is $x+G_i$ and so $x+G_i$ has to be open. Then the $\left\{x+G_i\right\}$ form a fundamental system of neighborhoods for $x$. To see this, let $U$ be an open set containing the point $y$. Let $V$ be the inverse image of $U$ under addition with $y$. Then $V$ must contain $0$ and so $V$ contains some $G_k$. It follows that $U$ contains $y+G_k$.

Are the above interpretations sound?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, both interpretations are correct (and in fact equivalent) although perhaps the second is a little more natural.
By definition a topological group is a group in which $$\cdot :G\times G\to G:(x,y)\mapsto x\cdot y$$ and $$^{-1}:G\to G:x\mapsto x^{-1}$$ are continuous maps. Therefore, a topology on a group $G$ which makes $G$ into a *topological group* is sufficiently characterised by a system of fundamental neighborhoods of some point $x\in G$. Note, however, that not every such system of neighborhoods for some point $x$ characterises a topology that makes $G$ a topological group, because $^{-1}$ may not be continuous. This is why we typically take a system of subgroups as a fundamental system of neighborhoods of $1$.

Comment: Thanks for your interesting answer. Could you please elaborate on your second to last sentence? What form would have a system of neighborhoods of an arbitrary point $x$? Would it be a family of cosets?

Comment: Not necessarily. It could be any family $\{B_i\}$ of subsets of $G$ satisfying $(1)$ $\forall i\in I: x\in B_i$ and $(2)$ for all $i,j\in I$, there is a $k\in I$ such that $B_k\subseteq B_i\cap B_j$.

Comment: So the problem is that if $B_i$ is an open set containing $x$, then the inverse image of $B_i$ under the inversion map is $-B_i$ and this need not be  a neighborhood of $-x$, i.e. $-B_i$ need not contain a set of the form $-x+B_j$, right? Also, why do we need condition (2)?

Comment: What are fundamental neighborhoods?